# How to display an array of objects on the page

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, object

currently this displays an array of objects on the page . I only want it to display the name and the points with a few spaces in between . for example , Player1   25  . I don't want anything else like the []{} etc

```
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>

Player1 = { name: 'Player1', points: 25 };
Player2 = { name: 'Player2', points: 50 };
Player3 = { name: 'Player3', points: 14 };

players = [Player1, Player2, Player3];

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(players) ;
```

Comment: Why not just loop over the objects and access the properties you want by key?

Answer (score 3):

Just loop through `players` and then spread the `values` of each `player`:

```js
var Player1 = {
  name: 'Player1',
  points: 25
};
var Player2 = {
  name: 'Player2',
  points: 50
};
var Player3 = {
  name: 'Player3',
  points: 14
};

var demo = document.getElementById("demo");

var players = [Player1, Player2, Player3];

players.forEach(player => demo.innerHTML += "<br>" + Object.values(player).join(" "));
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize a empty string and create span tags and concatenate the results. An approach of code is below in jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/trgwq7xy/

```
Player1 = { name: 'Player1', points: 25 };
Player2 = { name: 'Player2', points: 50 };
Player3 = { name: 'Player3', points: 14 };

players = [Player1, Player2, Player3];

html$ = '';
for(var key in players){
 html$ += '<span>'+players[key].name+', '+ players[key].points+'</span> ';
}

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = html$ ;
```